# C# Windows form using SQLite database, NullReference when open connection

Tags: c#, sqlite

This is my first work with SQLite.
I have this code to open the connection:

```
string cs = @"C:\DataBase\DataBase.db";
string connString = string.Format("Data Source={0};", cs);

conexion = new SqliteConnection(connString);
conexion.Open();
```

In the `Open()` line I got this error:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Why is that happening?

Comment: You need to use [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/)

Comment: @ruslanen - The question has nothing to do with the Entity Framework.

Comment: The `new` operator cannot return `null`. Are you showing real code?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, in general, there is.
He did not indicate which library he uses. I am assuming he is using a [library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite/). It has an open [issue](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/issues/324).

Comment: @ruslanen - I see.

Comment: Hello, I did what @ruslanen suggested and it worked.
The code is real.